# Downloading/Fetching Client session metadata from tokbox Inspector

Tags: tokbox

Given a session ID or for the last 10 sessions the Inspector tool provides interesting metrics regarding bitrate, packetloss and latency. **Is there an existing API or a way in which we can download this information for each session ID?**

Also would it be possible to fetch information of the sessions which are not the recent 10 via an API? If there's no API, is there a way I can log this information from each of the `ClientEvent` or `ClientQos` network requests to a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still learning Tokbox API. 
Currently, inspector is limited to 10 last sessions, and I never came across a method to call inspector using Tokbox API. Therefore, the best thing is to log the information by yourself.

In GitHub example [https://github.com/opentok/opentok-network-test], Tokbox has mentioned that using network stat API information regarding the packet drops and audio/ video framerates can be fetched if you are using Tokbox media router. 
Tokbox js developer reference has the same information, which I copy pasted below.
https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#getStats

> getStats(completionHandler)
>
> Returns the details on the subscriber
>   stream quality, including the following:
>
> • Total audio and video packets lost
>
> • Total audio and video packets received
>
> • Total audio and video bytes received
>
> • Current video frame rate

You should be able to save periodically the stats received by calling getStats() method to a database.

I will publish an example, based on my free time.